# How to read data from HTML date input on Servlet?

Tags: jsp, servlets

`<label>Birthday: </label> <input type="date" name="dob">`

I have tried reading the value using `dob`, but it gave an error.

Comment: "I have tried reading the value using dob, but it gave an error." What is error?

Comment: Well, it didn't print anything :/. 

I just don't know the correct way to read date data on servlet from HTML page. Can you please help me with the syntax?

Comment: Show your code for the html page and Servlet.

Answer (score 0):

What about google?

```
<form name="loginForm" method="post" action="loginServlet">
    Username: <input type="text" name="username"/> <br/>
    Password: <input type="password" name="password"/> <br/>
    <input type="submit" value="Login" />
</form>

@WebServlet("/loginServlet")
public class LoginServlet extends HttpServlet {
 
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
 
        String username = request.getParameter("username");
 
    }
 
}
```

Comment: Actually, I want to read a date from input. I know how simple inputs reading work.

Answer (score 0):

Make Sure,if you have defined 'POST' in form ,then the corresponding servlet code should be doPost()

Try This:

HTML:

```
    <form name="data" action="Test" method="POST">
    <label>Birthday: </label> <input type="date" name="dob">
    <input type="submit" value="submit">        
    </form>
```

Servlet:(inside doPost)

```
        String date=request.getParameter("dob");
        System.out.println("dateString:"+date);
        Date utilDate=new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-mm-dd").parse(date); 
        System.out.println("date:"+utilDate);
```

Note: Please give more details about a question such as how you want to read data from HTML to servlet eg: Using form tag, using AJAX, using javascript redirect.**As people on stackoverflow take efforts to provide solution.Kindly take Some effort while posting question.**

Answer (score 0):

File HTML/JSP:

```
<form name="date" action="getDate" method="POST">
   <input type="date" name="dob">
   <input type="submit" value="submit">        
</form>
```

In file Java:

```
String dob = (String) request.getParameter("dob");
Date dobDate = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-mm-dd").parse(dob);
```